# How to integrate Websockets with JSON API Resources in rails and ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember-data, jsonapi-resources

Is there a way to integrate JSONAPI::Resources gem to hub all data through websockets to ember?

Would also like to be able to push data out from ember to rails and have jsonapi resources pick it up and handle like a regular http request.

Thank you.